# Heroku error with devise invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise, devise-invitable

My app works in development, but when I try to launch my app in production (heroku) I am getting the following error:

/app/app/controllers/tenant/invitations_controller.rb:1:in `': uninitialized constant Tenants (NameError)

It looks like it has to do with the Devise Invitable (which I recently installed), and my app is setup to allow Managers to invite Tenants

Tenant Model

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :invite_for => 2.weeks

end
```

Invitations controller (located in my Tenants folder)

```
class Tenants::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController

  def new
    super
  end        

  def create
    super
  end

end
```

Manager Model

```
class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  include DeviseInvitable::Inviter

  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :maintenance_team

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tenants
  has_many :invitations, :class_name => 'Tenant', :as => :invited_by
end
```

routes

```
 devise_for :tenants,  controllers: { registrations: "tenant/registrations",  :invitations => 'devise/invitations'}
  devise_for :managers,  controllers: { sessions: "manager/sessions", registrations: "manager/registrations"}
```

Some Heroku logs

```
2016-07-15T04:50:53.147334+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:51919
2016-07-15T04:50:53.147345+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-07-15T04:50:53.147345+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2016-07-15T04:50:53.147352+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-07-15T04:50:53.147312+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2016-07-15T04:50:53.147366+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/tenant/invitations_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Tenants (NameError)
```

Production Config

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

host = 'project-apple.herokuapp.com'
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}


end
```

Comment: can you please paste your config/routes.rb over here? and also the some error logs?

Comment: just added, thank you!

Comment: did you notice that the logs contain "/app/app/controllers/tenant/invitations_controller.rb". I am wondering why there is double app/app are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing the routes to this.

```
devise_for :tenants,  controllers: { registrations: "tenant/registrations",  :invitations => 'tenant/invitations'}
```

Comment: that didn't work.  Also when I do that I get a similar error in development:  ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Tenants):
  app/controllers/tenant/invitations_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: This solution actually worked!  But I needed to change my invitations controller to:  `class Tenant::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController` from `class Tenants::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController `.  (Drop the s from Tenants)

Comment: might be you can change route to :invitations => 'tenants/invitations' this will point to Tenants::InvitationsController. I just use same as registrations which was earlier there.